# How to start the Laravel lockout counter after second unsuccessful login

Tags: php, laravel

I have used the below code in my login controller of Laravel:

```
 * Set how many failed logins are allowed before being locked out.
 */
public $maxAttempts = 2;

/**
 * Set how many seconds a lockout will last.
 */
public $decayMinutes = 1;
```

By the above code, after two unsuccessful logins, the user has to wait for 60 seconds or 1 minute.

For this, Laravel starts a counter after the first unsuccessful login, so when the user does the second unsuccessful login, it is showing the message "you can log in after 50 seconds".

I want to start this 60-seconds counter after the defined $maxAttempts.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding throttle middleware to your route.

```
Route::post("yourLogin","LoginController@login")->middleware("throttle:2,1");
```

Comment: Can you give me more detail about your answer?
I have added the code you have given but it didn't work

Comment: It is a bit terse. Can you elaborate in your answer? (But *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to clear your cache for the attempts to be reset.

Run `php artisan cache:clear` after making changes to `$maxAttempts` or `$decayMinutes` or in case you want to reset the attempts manually.